# Series of children's or YA books about magical dust

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a series of books I read back in maybe 2005 - 2010. I think there were three books, either in the children's category or YA.

They featured magic users who I believe were hidden in normal modern society and used magical dust which they carried with them in pouches to power their spells. The dust came in different colors, with the good magic users having white dust and the evil magic users having black dust.

The plot of the second book featured the evil magic users discovering a suit of armor that had been made by an evil magic user long ago entirely out of black dust, and they had ground up the gloves giving them an ample supply of black dust.

I believe the plot of the third book involved a giant cavern hidden in the earth (perhaps below Antarctica?) filled with all sorts of magical things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds a lot like the *[Night Witches](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?23928)* series by Michael Molloy.

The series deals with the battle between good magic users, armed with white "Ice Dust", and evil magic users armed with "Black dust". I believe the plot concerning the suit of armor actually arises in the third book in the trilogy, *Wild West Witches*. From a review on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2167631.Wild_West_Witches):

> In this installment Abby, Spike and the gang are transported through
> time with Merlin's sword to escape the evil Wolfbane who needs the
> sword to cut up a magical suit of armour to give him magical black
> dust to defeat the witches but due to a glitch they all end up in the
> American Wild West!

Antarctica appeared in the first book in the series, *The Witch Trade*, in which the characters travel there to replenish their supplies of Ice Dust.

Comment: Ah ha! I considered suggesting the magic users might be called witches but thought I had probably made that bit up... Also is it Night Witches or Light Witches? Your answer says Night but the linked page says Light.

Comment: @user22919 I'm pretty sure it's the "Night Witches" series - there must be a mistake on the isfdb entry

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez Goodreads agrees with you, but Librarything disagrees.  Posts on ebay tend to say "Night witches," but most descriptions don't name the series at all, just the individual titles.   https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2167631.Wild_West_Witches   https://www.librarything.com/work/386346

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis "Light witches" and "Night witches" are the names of the two factions, so I guess either would make sense as a name for the trilogy. I'd only ever heard it referred to as the Night Witch books though. There is no indication on the bookcovers what the correct term is, so I suppose either is acceptable.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis But doesn't the librarything link you give call the series "The Night Witches"?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez True, I was pointing out that the two sources I could find didn't even agree on which it was.  (When I was typing I forgot which side you were on.)  My point is that there doesn't seem to be a solid canonical answer, and you're right, either makes sense.  My personal inclination would be to give the protagonists the title spot, but these days that might be considered doxxing.  :-)